# php-fpm slow unknown 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

My Nginx appear nginx_elapsed. I see my php-fpm slow log.

```
script_filename = /home/work/www/order/index.php 
[0x00007f04508ca378] mysqli_query() /home/work/www/order/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:179 [0x00007f04508c9ee8] _execute() /home/work/www/order/application/core/database/DB_driver.php:465 
[0x00007f04508c8a58] simple_query() /home/work/www/order/application/core/database/DB_driver.php:298 
[0x00007f04508c8748] query() /home/work/www/order/system/database/DB_active_rec.php:962 
[0x00007f04508c8138] get() /home/work/www/order/application/models/api_model.php:309
[0x00007f04508c7a68] get_sales_appointment() /home/work/www/order/application/controllers/api.php:412 
[0x00007fffa9508440] appointment_alert_get() unknown:0 
[0x00007f04508c7978] call_user_func_array() /home/work/www/order/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php:442 [0x00007f04508c69f0] _fire_method() /home/work/www/order/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php:429 [0x00007f04508c4908] _remap() /home/work/www/order/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:328 
[0x00007f04508c4148] +++ dump failed
```

I want to know the meaning of `appointment_alert_get() unknown:0`